# How can I reject the ajax() Promise from within the dataFilter function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, promise

This is mainly from a curiosity point of view, is it possible to put some application error handling in the `dataFilter` method so even though the `ajax()` returned a `200` with valid data type, I can test the data for "logical" errors and force a `reject` on the `Promise` itself.

The idea is that any application error in my REST API always returns a standard error JSON , so im hoping to do some intercepting and redirection to the done/fail method after testing if the response is an error.

This will allow me to put the code for testing the response for errors in the `global AJAX settings` and allow individual `fail()` methods to implement context-specific behavior.

**Here is a simplified example:**

```
 /*
 * Global AJAX settings
 * */
$.ajaxSetup({
  dataType: "text",
  dataFilter: function(data, type) {
    if (typeof(data.iamanerror)!="undefined")
      return 'i am an error,id like to be handled by the fail handler'
    return 'success';
  }
});

$.post("/echo/json/").done(function(data) {
  console.log(data)
}).fail(function(a, b, c) {
  console.log(data)
});
```

**Fiddle:**

https://jsfiddle.net/ae96gtqr/1/

**note:**

I am using `jQuery 1.12.4`

Comment: Better do it in a `then` handler locally (but possibly using a globally defined function). Which jQuery version are you using?

Comment: @Bergi updated the question to mention jq version.. 1.12.4